# Trying to get specific values from nested dictionary based on user input

Tags: python

I'm trying to get specific values from a nested dictionary based on user input. The code I have so far returns 'None None.' Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
customer_dict = {
    "ctmr1" : {
        "Fname" : "John",
        "Lname" : "Smith",
        "Username" : "smithj",
        "Password" : "123"
    },
    "ctmr2" : {
        "Fname" : "Anita",
        "Lname" : "Job",
        "Username" : "joba",
        "Password" : "456"
    }
}

usrnm = input("Enter username: ")
psw = input("Enter password: ")

u = customer_dict.get("Username",{}).get(usrnm)
p = customer_dict.get("Password", {}).get(psw)

print (u,p)

if usrnm != u or psw != p:
    print("Wrong credentials")
else:
    print("Welcome!")
```

Comment: Debugging tip: break up complex expressions so that you can see the intermediate values: `d = customer_dict.get("Username", {}); print(d); u = d.get(usrnm)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve your problem

```
usrnm = input("Enter username: ")
psw = input("Enter password: ")

found_flag = False
for ctmr in customer_dict:
  u = customer_dict[ctmr].get("Username")
  p = customer_dict[ctmr].get("Password")
  if usrnm != u or psw != p:
    continue
  else:
    found_flag = True
    break

if found_flag == True:
  print('Welcome')
else:
  print('Wrong Credentials')
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to get dictionary by username in first level, but username in the nested dict
you need to get the nested dict first,

try a function like this, to get the user dict first

```
def get_user(users,username):
    for user in users.values():
        if user['Username'] == username:
            return user
```

then you could

```
uer = get_user(customer_dict,usrnm)
```

but i suggest rearrangin the dict, so as to have username as the key
like

```
customer_dict = {
    "smithj" : {
        "Fname" : "John",
        "Lname" : "Smith",
        "Password" : "123"
    },
    ...
}
```

so instead of all this you could just do

```
customer_dict.get('username')
```